# Countdown timer doesn't start

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have the code bellow and I'm trying to make a countdown timer about the time left for the game to end. I've got to read the serverTime value and the endPlayTime value but I do not get time to go back in the countdown timer.

This is my code (UPDATED):

```
public void NewGameScore()
{
   ScorePCH = 0;
   TextoContador.text = "0";
   ES2.Save(ScorePCH, ScorePlayerCH);

   _bc.TournamentService.GetTournamentStatus(leaderboardId, versionId, successCallback2, failureCallback2);

    }

private void successCallback(string jsonResponse, object cbObject)
{
    var ZserverTime = JsonMapper.ToObject(jsonResponse)["data"]["server_time"];
    string _ZserverTime = ZserverTime.ToString();
    Debug.Log(_ZserverTime);
    PlayerPrefs.SetString("ZserverTime", _ZserverTime);

    var ZtPlayEnd = JsonMapper.ToObject(jsonResponse)["data"]["tournamentTimetable"]["tPlayEnd"];
    string _ZtPlayEnd = ZtPlayEnd.ToString();
    Debug.Log(_ZtPlayEnd);
    PlayerPrefs.SetString("ZtPlayEnd", _ZtPlayEnd);

    StartCoroutine("LoseTime");
    Time.timeScale = 1; //Just making sure that the timeScale is right
}

private void failureCallback(int status, int reasonCode, string jsonError, object cbObject)
{
    Debug.Log("Error al listar desafíos");
}

IEnumerator LoseTime()
{
    Debug.Log("ejecuta losetime...");

    long serverTime = Convert.ToInt64(PlayerPrefs.GetString("ZserverTime"));
    string _serverTime = serverTime.ToString();
    Debug.Log(_serverTime);

    long endPlayTime = Convert.ToInt64(PlayerPrefs.GetString("ZtPlayEnd"));
    string _endPlayTime = endPlayTime.ToString();
    Debug.Log(_endPlayTime);

    int StimeLeft = (int)(endPlayTime - serverTime);
    string _StimeLeft = StimeLeft.ToString();
    Debug.Log(_StimeLeft);
    //int StimeLeft = 120;

    while (true)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
        StimeLeft--;
        countdown.text = ("" + StimeLeft);
    }

}
```

Comment: In your LoseTime function, you are decreasing the StimeLeft variable but are not reassigning this value to "Ftiempo", which is what your text is using to display the time. You need to update "Ftiempo" to match the decreasing value of StimeLeft in your loop.

Comment: Or if you want to keep the variable at the function level, then move your `int PtimeLeft = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Ftiempo");
    countdown.text = ("" + PtimeLeft);` script out of the update, change it to reference StimeLeft, and put it in your loop inside LoseTime. There's no need to update the text unless the time is changing anyways, so you may as well put it inside the coroutine as well.

Comment: @TimHunter I've updated the code removing the update. When I use a value like "int StimeLeft = 120" the countdown works fine but when use "int StimeLeft = (int)(endPlayTime - serverTime);" the time doesn't go back in the countdown timer

Comment: Hmmm, if it's working with a set value but not the one you're pulling then I would suspect either the value you're getting from the server is getting messed up somehow (but you said these are reading correctly) or the conversion from long to int is messing up somehow. Maybe try the `Convert.ToInt32(myValue);` method of conversion instead?